# DialogFlow sets 12:00:00 as a beginning of the day if time isn't specified in text

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm learning to build chat bots using DialogFlow. As an example I created simple intent to report my current weight. I built endpoint on my server to receive data as fulfillment requests to save it into data base.

As data parameters I specified weight as @sys.unit-weight and date as @sys.date. When I specify date by words "today" or "tomorrow", date part is parsed correct but DialogFlow adds 12:00:00 as a time part. It's a bit odd and I can't really understand what's the point of that time. It looks incorrect.

I'm attaching screenshot of executing intent in DialogFlow's console and also fulfillment request payload. Does anybody have an idea how to get dates without time or with 00:00:00 if time hasn't been provided?

[Screen shot of triggering intent by DialogFlow's console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28IVo.png)

```
 {
  "responseId": "518945f5-33bf-43a8-86ce-42e422033e6c-425db6e2",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "yes",
    "action": "TrackWeight",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Your weight log was saved. Do you want anything else?",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Your weight log was saved. Do you want anything else?"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/chatbot-59dda/agent/sessions/414dfa61-4850-eb27-804a-afea25516ab8/contexts/trackweight-followup",
        "parameters": {
          "weight": {
            "amount": 50,
            "unit": "kg"
          },
          "weight.original": "50 kg",
          "date": "2020-07-09T12:00:00+03:00",
          "date.original": "today"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/chatbot-59dda/agent/sessions/414dfa61-4850-eb27-804a-afea25516ab8/contexts/__system_counters__",
        "parameters": {
          "no-input": 0,
          "no-match": 0
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/chatbot-59dda/agent/intents/c8bafb9d-1c44-401c-877f-9929d4fc23c2",
      "displayName": "Track Weight - yes"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "payload": {}
  },
  "session": "projects/chatbot-59dda/agent/sessions/414dfa61-4850-eb27-804a-afea25516ab8"
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the format Dialogflow reports date/time. All you need to do is to separate the date and time and convert it to the format that you need.
You can access date or time by `agent.parameters.date` or `agent.parameter.time` and the format still will be the same. Here are some functions that could help:

```
function convertParametersDateTime(date, time){
     return new Date(Date.parse(date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + time.split('T')[1].split('+')[0]));
}


// A helper function that adds the integer value of 'hoursToAdd' to the Date instance 'dateObj' and return a new Data instance.
function addHours(dateObj, hoursToAdd){
    return new Date(new Date(dateObj).setHours(dateObj.getHours() + hoursToAdd));
}

// A helper funciton that converts the Date instance 'dateObj' into a string that represents this time in English.
function getLocaleTimeString(dateObj){
    return dateObj.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour: 'numeric', hour12: true});
}

// A helper dunction that converts the Date instance 'dateObj' into a string that represents this date in English
function getLocaleDateString(dateObj){
    return dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {weekday: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'});
}
```

The idea is you can split by `'T'` and use the part that you need

Comment: Thanks, @Gray_Rhino! If I split date and time by 'T' symbol I'll still get 12:00:00 in the time part. And I can't rely on it, because system doesn't know if noon time is provided or DialogFlow puts that time as a beginning of the day. But I like your idea to split date and time into different parameters. Date as sys.date and time as sys.time. I'll keep this question open for a while. May be somebody will give more in depth explanation of that behavior.

Comment: for the date you should use agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] which gives you the correct date and the time will always be 12:00:00. However, for the time you should use agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1] which will give you the correct time and the date will always be current date. For example, when you tell your agent to "do something next Monday at 8pm" your agent.parameters.date will be "***2020-07-20***T12:00:00" and agent.parameters.time will be "2020-07-13T***20:00:00***". See the difference?